# Android dpi-based resource not found

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources, dpi

I'm running a low dpi QVGA Slider (API 5) AVD emulator running Android 2.0.

`getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi` returns 120, which is the standard value for ldpi.

I have resource folders `values`, `values-ldpi`, `values-mdpi`, `values-hdpi`, ..., `values xxxhdpi`. Each contain a `numbers.xml` file, which all hold a different value of the integer variable `edit_text_padding`. However, when I try to access this value using `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.edit_text_padding)`, the value from the default `values` folder is used instead.

However, when I changed the API level of the emulator up to 19, it started working.

Is there a specific API level where customizable resource folders were added?